# Centering an image with an input?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, html

I have an image next to an input, and I was wondering how I centered both with one another. I need the center of the image to be vertically aligned with the center of the input. How do I make this happen?

**Markup:**

```
<span class="my-span">
  <input type="text" .../><a href="..."><img .../></a>
</span>
```

Comment: Did you try the methods described in this link: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the vertical-align to middle on the `<img>` should put you in business:

```
<span class="my-span">
    <input type="text" .../><a href="..."><img ... style="vertical-align: middle"/></a>
</span>
```

You can see it [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/vu3tk/).

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Something must be styling the <input> to cause it to be offset somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Your image should have the ff styles to work:

```
img { vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell; }
```

and to your input element, add

```
input { float: left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting vertical-align on both input and img elements works for me:

```
<span class="my-span">
   <input type="text" style="vertical-align: middle" /><a href="..." ><img style="vertical-align: middle" ... /></a>
</span>
```

[Check it here](http://jsfiddle.net/h77ZW/)